# JQuery DataTable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create table with DataTable library (that using foundation-zurb),
This is the table html code:

```
 <table  dir="rtl" id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%; " >
            <thead style="margin-top:0%;">

            <tr class="top-table" >
                <th><label class="tableHeaders">מספר</label></th>
                <th><label class="tableHeaders"><fmt:message key="email" /></label></th>
                <th><label class="tableHeaders"><fmt:message key="department1" /></label></th>
                <th><label style="float:right;"><fmt:message key="role1" /></label></th>
                <th></th>


            </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${listAdmin_user}"  var="Admin_user" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${Admin_user.email}</td>

                    <td>${Admin_user.departmentObj.inCurrentLanguage}</td>
                    <td>${Admin_user.roleObj.inCurrentLanguage}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="editAdmin_user?id=${Admin_user.id}"><img src="resources/images/update.gif"></a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="deleteAdmin_user?id=${Admin_user.id}"><img src="resources/images/erase.gif"></a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
          </c:forEach>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

also I added this scripts to my html file:
(to initial the table and add DataTable files that located in my project folders)

```
 <script src="r/lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="r/lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="r/lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js"></script>



<script src="resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Responsive-2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

 <script>
      $(document).foundation();
      $(document).ready(function() {

          var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable( 
         {

             "language": {
                 "url": "resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/hebrew.json"
             },
           "columnDefs": [ {

             "targets": [5,6],
             "orderable": false
             },
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 5 },
            { responsivePriority: 4, targets: 6 }
           ],

             responsive: true,

         }

         );

         $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
             dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
         });    


         $("#searchbox").on("keyup search input paste cut", function() {
           dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
        }); 
      });



   </script>
```

(on the end of jsp page).

Here is the links:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/css/foundation.css">
    <link href="resources/cssf/addCss.css?version=6" rel="stylesheet" >  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/dataTables.foundation.min.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/Responsive-2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"/>
     <link href="r/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

My problem is that the DataTable not working,
I get error on this line in js file:

```
i._DT_CellIndex={row:b,column:l};g.push(i);if((!c||n.mRender||n.mData!==l)&&(!h.isPlainObject(n.mData)||n.mData._!==l+".display"))i.innerHTML=B(a,b,l,"display");n.sClass&&(i.className+=" "+n.sClass);n.bVisible&&!c?j.appendChild(i):!n.bVisible&&c&&i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
```

I also using DataTable in another pages and its working fine, only on this page I got this error.
Someone have any idea about my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mismatch in the number of header columns cause this issue, there should be equal number of header columns and the row columns.
Please change your script to below script it will work for you !!!.

```
<script>
      $(document).foundation();
      $(document).ready(function() {

          var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable( 
         {

             "language": {
                 "url": "resources/DataTables-1.10.12/DataTables-1.10.12/hebrew.json"
             },
           "columnDefs": [ {

               "targets": [2,3],
             "orderable": false
             },
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 2 },
            { responsivePriority: 4, targets: 3 }
           ],
             responsive: true,
         });

         $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
             dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
         });   
         $("#searchbox").on("keyup search input paste cut", function() {
           dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
        }); 
      });

   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! its working now! can I add my second table to the question and you will add the changes for this table in the answer? Its not working too... ??